# Attaching multiple types to a multifunctional component isn't working as expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following component which originally was just a grid of `Desk` records but I'm trying to refactor it to also accommodate `Booking` records and make it multi-functional.

Here is the component code:

```js
/* Render component */
export const DeskGrid: React.FC<Props> = ({
  columns,
  desks,
  bookings,
  dates,
  buttonAction,
  showFilter
}: Props) => {
  const [deskList, setDeskList] = useState(desks);
  const list: Desk[] | Booking[] = deskList || bookings;

  return (
    <>
      {desks && showFilter && (
        <div className={styles['filter']}>
          <DeskFilter
            filterAction={(e: SyntheticEvent): void =>
              setDeskList(filterStateByInput(e, 'name', desks))
            }
          />
        </div>
      )}
      <ul
        className={cx(
          styles['desk-grid'],
          columns && styles[`desk-grid-${columns}-up`]
        )}
      >
        {list.map((listItem: Desk | Booking) => (
          <li key={`desk-${listItem.id}`}>
            {desks && <DeskCard desk={listItem} dates={dates} buttonAction={buttonAction} />}
            {bookings && (
              <DeskCard booking={listItem} buttonAction={buttonAction} />
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Functionally, this code works as expected, however I'm getting a type error on this part:

```js
  {list.map((listItem: Desk | Booking) => (
          <li key={`desk-${listItem.id}`}>
            {desks && <DeskCard desk={listItem} dates={dates} buttonAction={buttonAction} />}
            {bookings && (
              <DeskCard booking={listItem} buttonAction={buttonAction} />
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
```

`Type 'Desk | Booking' is not assignable to type 'Booking'. Type 'Desk' is missing the following properties from type 'Booking': startDateTime, endDateTimets(2322)`

If I hover over `list`, I see that it only has the `Desk[]` type and is ignoring the booking type. I'm not sure what is going on here or how to fix it. Could anyone help?

Comment: `<DeskCard booking={listItem} buttonAction={buttonAction} />` i believe the error is in this line. You may set `DeskCard` prop type to only `Booking`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you assign **listItem** to **booking**, TypeScript doesn't know that listItem should be a *Booking* type at that point, and since it could be missing properties it raises that compiler error.  It likely shows *Desk[]* when you hover over **list** because the properties of the *Desk* are all encompassed by *Book*, so *Desk | Book* is equivalent to *Desk*.

You could write a type guard function or just separate the code into two different loops for each array.  Using two different loops would actually be more efficient since you wouldn't need the conditional check for each iteration.

Below is a solution implementing a type guard.  By using the type guard, the compiler will know that whatever is being passed to **bookings** will be a Booking type when the result of the function is true.

```
export const DeskGrid: React.FC<Props> = ({columns, desks, bookings, dates, buttonAction, showFilter }: Props) => {
  const [deskList, setDeskList] = useState(desks);
  const list: Desk[] | Booking[] = deskList || bookings;

  // isBooking returns true if deskList is nullish.  Obviously not a universal solution.
  const isBooking = (x: Desk | Booking): x is Booking => !deskList;
  
  return (
    <>
      {desks && showFilter && (
        <div className={styles['filter']}>
          <DeskFilter
            filterAction={(e: SyntheticEvent): void =>
              setDeskList(filterStateByInput(e, 'name', desks))
            }
          />
        </div>
      )}
      <ul
        className={cx(
          styles['desk-grid'],
          columns && styles[`desk-grid-${columns}-up`]
        )}
      >
        {deskList.map((listItem) => (
          <li key={`desk-${listItem.id}`}>
            { isBooking(listItem)
              ? <DeskCard booking={listItem} buttonAction={buttonAction} />
              : <DeskCard desk={listItem} dates={dates} buttonAction={buttonAction} />
            }
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: *smacks head* of course, separate loops make more sense. I think I was trying to be clever and failed miserably. Thank you, that resolved my issue.